# C programming practice, passing a pointer to a function

Tags: c, coding-style

Consider the following C function which takes as argument a string, which is then stored inside a struct:

```
struct mystruct* usestring(char* string)
{
    struct mystruct *struct;
    struct = malloc(sizeof(struct mystruct));
    struct->string = string;
    return struct;
}
```

My understanding is that the string passed to the function is the same string that is stored inside the struct.

What is the proper etiquette in this situation? Should I make a copy of the string and store that in the struct, or should I expect that the function caller will not modify the string later?

Comment: This is way too broad to answer. It's often to be expected, but also often unexpected. Ownership of dynamically allocated memory is a **huge** topic; in fact, people have written entire new languages with garbage collection mainly to escape the problems brought about by correctly tracking such ownership.

Comment: I would think the objectively correct thing to do is **document your choice**. You have no clue who might use this function in the future and trying to predict what they'll expect is an exercise in futility. If you find by using this function you want some other ownership behavior, update the function and perhaps add some rational for the new behavior in the documentation

Comment: You should assume anything could happen unless the documentation says otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I felt like I might be doing something wrong by having it possible to damage the contents of the struct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will always depend on many factors, but as elementary guidance:

1. For pointers to `const`, ownership should *not* be transferred and the callee should not assume the pointed object will continue to exist after it returns.
2. For pointers to **non**-`const`, ownership transfer must be **documented**. Whether ownership is transferred or not is a matter of what is more practical in the particular place.
3. Pointers should be to `const` whenever possible.

This is not always the most efficient thing to do (you sometimes copy when the object actually will continue to exist), but it is a way to reduce the number of places where you have to be careful.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, it depends on context.

Consider the following code, which creates new instances of `struct mystruct` and adds them to a list:

```
while ( some_condition )
{
  char inputString[SIZE];
  if ( getInput( inputString ) )
  {
    struct mystruct *newStruct = usestring( inputString );
    addEntry( list, newStruct );
    ...
  }
}
```

Every instance of `newStruct` in the list will wind up pointing to the same string; even better, that pointer will be invalid after the `while` loop exits.

*In this particular case*, you should make a copy of the input string and store that to the struct.  Of course, that opens up questions about how that memory is to be recovered, who's responsible for it, etc.